# join two tables of data regardless of the null data

Tags: mysql, join

so I have two tables, kind of look like this;

```
table_a                            table_b
reg     |rm     |date              reg     |rm     |date
========+=======+==========        ========+=======+==========
1       |1      |2013-01-01        2       |2      |2013-01-01
1       |1      |2013-01-02        2       |2      |2013-01-05
3       |2      |2013-01-08        3       |2      |2013-01-08
```

*-I know it look like two different table that have same data but actually it has different column, I just didn't include any other column that not related to this question*

this is what I'm trying to achieve when I search by `rm=2`;

```
result
reg     |date
========+==========
3       |2013-01-08
2       |2013-01-01
```

when I tried using `join`, `reg 2` in `table_b` didn't appear, when I tried with `union all` it says `reg` can not be null because I use `min(date)` to get earliest date. (it did't error when I remove `min` function but it will show every date - I only need earliest date and `order by date desc`)

this is my query to achieve that;

```
SELECT b.reg, min(b.date) as ddate
FROM table_a a 
join table_b b on (o.reg=a.reg) 
where b.rm = '2'
order by ddate desc
```

and this

```
select reg,min(date) as ddate from table_a where rm = '2'                  
union all
select reg,min(date) as ddate from table_b where rm = '2'
order by ddate desc
```

Comment: can you show us your actual query?

Comment: Tables look good. However, I can't understand what you're doing to get the result. Can you explain that?

Comment: Also, here's an excellent resource for figuring out what different types of joins do: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html (though mySQL doesn't have FULL OUTER JOIN).

Comment: What is your expected result if both records have the same reg and date? 1 record or 2 equal records? (After your edit I see what you're doing... and your data was indeed wrong :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several duplicate keys and only need 1 it's `GROUP BY`, if you want to lowest first, it's `ORDER BY ... ASC`

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a WHERE a.rm = 2 GROUP BY a.reg ORDER BY a.date ASC
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_b b WHERE b.rm = 2 GROUP BY b.reg ORDER BY b.date ASC
```

I didn't 100% understand why you have 2 different tables for the same stuff, maybe you need to UNION first and then GROUP BY:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table_b
) x
WHERE x.rm = 2
GROUP BY x.reg
ORDER BY x.date ASC
```

Comment: Can you limit 1 on the sub queries?

Comment: Do you think its neccessary?

Comment: It is possible, but the subqueries need to be wrapped in parenthesis. And, yes, based on OP stating they only want earliest date per subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select reg, min(date)
from (
    (select reg, rm, date from table_a)
    UNION
    (select reg, rm, date from table_b)
) union_tbl
where rm = 2
group by reg
```